# Using the Ace Code Editor, can I search and return results to variable?

Tags: regex, search, ace-editor

I'm using the Ace Code Editor for a Chrome extension. I know how to perform a search and replace, it's pretty well documented here: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto

But is there a way I can perform a search matching a regex expression and just have the results return and stored in a variable? I'm trying to guess the tab indenting on an existing document, so I want to search the document for leading whitespace on each line, and be able to compare results

Answer (score 0):

Ace have built in module for detecting indentation see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ext/whitespace.js#L105.
You can see it in action in kitchen-sink demo. It is called from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/kitchen-sink/demo.js#L344

As about using the search api for this, it will be slow, using regex like Ace does is the correct way.